# Multi Tenancy Report Solution

Tags: trigger, reporting, multi-tenant

I have a separate database per a client although data structure is same for all databases. Only difference is all clients have their own data on their on databases. Now problem is when I need a report that includes all clients, it is a big concern. As each client has millions of data and union will not work as it will take too much time. I have already applied indices on important columns. I have tried with triggers as well, but it creates lock many times.

I want to create a report database server, where I can create a flat table structure and can put all clients data into that with separate client id.

So is there any way I can modify bean logs so that I can create a flat table structure in a report database.
For Example,
Each client has Table A,B,C.
In Report I want column 1,2 of Table A, column 2,3 of Table B and column 5 of Table C of all clients.

Please note that I do not want to use trigger.

It can be resolved with ActiveMQ from application side. I am just curious about solution from database side.

Comment: And your RDBMS is? Machine config - CPU, RAM, HDD?

Comment: What is "bean logs"?  Also, not using a trigger but wanting a database-side solution might be eliminating sensible solutions.  What is the problem with triggers?